# Difference between file open modes in c

Tags: c, file

It says in both r+ and w+ we can read and write a file.so in what way r+ and w+ are different??

In what file modes Can we write in a middle of a file.Here i want to overwrite the content of a file at particular position and not inserting.

Comment: `In what file modes Can we write in a middle of a file overwriting the contents` None of them  (if you meant to say **without** overwriting the contents).

Comment: As long as the OP doesn't change the question, there is no reason to assume that he didn't mean what he actually wrote.

Comment: Have you googled it? Pretty trivial to find out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58419418/12114801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r` open text file for reading
`w` create text file for writing; discard previous contents if any
`a` append; open or create text file for writing at end of file
`r+` open text file for update (i.e., reading and writing)
`w+` create text file for update; discard previous contents of any
`a+` append; open or create text file for update, writing at end

in both `w` and `w+` modes u can write using fseek. Note that w+ creates a file if it doesn't exists!

Answer (score 0):

The `w+` mode will truncate (empty) the file. So if you want to change the contents rather than write a new file, use `r+`. Note that, as Tim Cooper noted, you cannot append in the middle of the file, so you can overwite certain parts using `fseek` and the write functions. But you cannot insert some text in the middle without rewriting everything that comes after it.